# How to have two root websites on one IIS server

Tags: iis

I have a website on the IIS as the default website. It is in "**c:\interpub\wwwroot**". When I request "**www.mysite1.com**", I get to this site.

Now I want to add a second website on the **same IIS server**. I want to store it in "**c:\mysecondsite**". When I request "**www.mysite2.com**", I wish to get to this second site.

**NOTE**: I don't want the **second site** to become an **application** inside the **first site**. In other words, I don't want to access the second site using "**www.mysite1.com/mysite2**".

How do I do it?

Comment: You need to create a new website in IIS. Check https://tecadmin.net/create-website-in-iis/

Comment: It’s in the bindings, you need to tell Iis what application to activate depending on the requested domain. Testing this locally you may need to fiddle with your hosts file

Comment: I know all these in theory. I created the first website myself and it has been working fine. I just don't know how to add a SECOND site. Any detailed step-by-step procedure?